# Access another Masterpage from this.Masterpage's content page

Tags: c#, master-pages

I have a two master page and i want to access another masterpage's controls from masterpage. i try this code but don't running

```
ContentPlaceHolder cphDepartmant = 
    (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("cphMainContent");
BIMSA.Web.UI.Controls.Textbox comboDepartment = 
    ((BIMSA.Web.UI.Controls.Textbox)cphDepartmant.FindControl("txtTedarikci"));
```

How to access another masterpage file ?

Comment: try using `Page.FindControl(...)` from master page

Comment: thanks Lanorkin, i try this  but don't work